# Nested facets with java api

Tags: java, solr

I have the following nested facets which is a sum over time

```
{
    "query": "*:*",
    "facet": {
         "daterange": {
             "type": "range",
             "field": "created_date",
             "start": "2019-07-10T18:34:10Z",
             "end": "2019-07-11T19:51:56Z",
             "gap": "+8640000MILLISECONDS",
             "facet": {
                 "x":"sum(price)"
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it supported in the solr java api?

I was expecting to be able to pass a facet object as an argument

```
public SolrQuery addDateRangeFacet(String field, Date start, Date end, String gap) {
    add(FacetParams.FACET_RANGE, field);
    add(String.format(Locale.ROOT, "f.%s.%s", field, FacetParams.FACET_RANGE_START), start.toInstant().toString());
    add(String.format(Locale.ROOT, "f.%s.%s", field, FacetParams.FACET_RANGE_END),   end.toInstant().toString());
    add(String.format(Locale.ROOT, "f.%s.%s", field, FacetParams.FACET_RANGE_GAP),   gap);
    this.set(FacetParams.FACET, true);
    return this;
  }
```

Using org.apache.solr-solrj 7.0.1

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for answers for a nested facet using SolrQuery in Java, just found this post:
https://chakrayel.wordpress.com/2017/03/30/consuming-json-facet-api/
Based on this the solution for your case would be something like this I guess (pseudo-syntax):

```
SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
query.set("json.facet", """{
               "daterange": {
               "type": "range",
               "field": "created_date",
               "start": "2019-07-10T18:34:10Z",
               "end": "2019-07-11T19:51:56Z",
               "gap": "+8640000MILLISECONDS",
               "facet": {
               "x":"sum(price)"
            }
        }""");
```

I haven't tested the post yet.

HTH.